# Clear content of clickable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a grid of divs (in a table) that are all clickable and on clicking any of the divs, a modal form pops up which can be filled and a summary of the form will be displayed into respective divs. Through some very bad coding I have managed to get that working but I also need to add a 'remove' option to remove everything in that div. So far, I add an 'a' tag labelled 'X' onto the div after filling in the form but its not clearing the div and instead, firing up the div's click event even though I used stopPropogation() method as suggested in some other thread.

Here are my futile attempts:

Div's click event:

```
$('.blueBox').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
...}
```

a tag added to the div:

```
<a class='remove' href='#'>X</a>
```

a tag's click event:

```
$('a').click(function (e) {
        e.stopPropogation();
        if (this.parentNode && this.parentNode.id){
            var parentId=this.parentNode.id;
            document.getElementById(parentId).innerHTML = "";
        }
    });
```

here's the full js file:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 

    //select all the a tag with name equal to modal
    $('.blueBox').click(function(e) {
        //Cancel the link behavior
        e.preventDefault();
        //Get the clicked div
        var divId = $(this).attr('id');
        $('#dayInfo').text(getDay(divId) + " " + getTime(divId));
        $('#btnOk').attr('name', divId);

        //Set id to modal dialog
        var id = "#dialog";

        //Get the screen height and width
        var maskHeight = $(document).height();
        var maskWidth = $(window).width();

        //Set height and width to mask to fill up the whole screen
        $('#mask').css({'width':maskWidth,'height':maskHeight});

        //transition effect    
        $('#mask').fadeIn(1000);   
        $('#mask').fadeTo("slow",0.8); 

        //Get the window height and width
        var winH = $(window).height();
        var winW = $(window).width();

        //Set the popup window to center
        $(id).css('top',  winH/2-$(id).height()/2);
        $(id).css('left', winW/2-$(id).width()/2);

        //transition effect
        $(id).fadeIn(2000);

    });

    //if close button is clicked
    $('.window .close').click(function (e) {
        //Cancel the link behavior
        e.preventDefault();
        $('#mask, .window').hide();
    });    

     $('.blueBox a.remove').click(function (e) {
        //Cancel the link behavior
        e.stopPropagation();
        // if (this.parentNode && this.parentNode.id){
            // var parentId=this.parentNode.id;
            // document.getElementById(parentId).innerHTML = "";
        // }
        this.parentNode.innerHTML = "";

    }); 

    //if mask is clicked
    $('#mask').click(function () {
        $(this).hide();
        $('.window').hide();
    });

    //if OK button is clicked
    $('.window .ok').click(function (e) {
        //Cancel the link behavior
        e.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).attr('name');
        document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = buildHtml();
        $('#mask, .window').hide();
    });

});

function buildHtml(){
    var output;
    output = document.getElementById('txtDept').value + "<br />";
    output += document.getElementById('txtModule').value + "<br />";
    output += document.getElementById('txtTitle').value + "<br />";
    output += document.getElementById('txtHours').value;
    output += "<a class='remove' href='#'>X</a>";
    return output;
}
```

Here's the full html file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel = "stylesheet" type = "text/css" href = "TeamSite.css" />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jfunc.js"></script>


</head>
<body>
<div id='mainContent'>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <th>09:00 - 09:50</th>
            <th>10:00 - 10:50</th>
            <th>11:00 - 11:50</th>
            <th>12:00 - 12:50</th>
            <th>13:00 - 13:50</th>
            <th>14:00 - 14:50</th>
            <th>15:00 - 15:50</th>
            <th>16:00 - 16:50</th>
            <th>17:00 - 17:50</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><div id="Mon1" class='blueBox'></div></td>
            <td><div id="Mon2" class='blueBox'></div></td>
            <td><div class='blueBox'></div></td>
            <td><div class='blueBox'></div></td>
            <td><div class='blueBox'></div></td>
            <td><div class='blueBox'></div></td>
            <td><div class='blueBox'></div></td>
            <td><div class='blueBox'></div></td>
            <td><div class='blueBox'></div></td>
        </tr>
    </table>

    <a href="#dialog" name="modal">Simple Modal Window</a>

<div id="boxes">


    <!-- #customize your modal window here -->

    <div id="dialog" class="window">
        <b>Testing of Modal Window</b> |

        <!-- close button is defined as close class -->
        <a href="#" class="close">Close it</a>

        <p id='dayInfo'></p>

        <div id='form'>
            <form>
                <p>
                    <label>Department: </label><input type="text" id="txtDept" />
                </p>

                <p>
                    <label>Module Code: </label><input type="text" id="txtModule" />
                </p>

                <p>
                    <label>Module Title: </label><input type="text" id="txtTitle" />
                </p>

                <p>
                    <label>No. of hours: </label><input type="text" id="txtHours" />
                </p>

                <p>
                    <input type="button" value="OK" class="ok" id="btnOk" /><input type="button" class="close" value="Cancel" id="btnCancel" />
                </p>
            </form> 
        </div>
    </div>


    <!-- Do not remove div#mask, because you'll need it to fill the whole screen --> 
    <div id="mask"></div>
</div>

</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Can you post a sample of representative code, to show what html you're working with?

Answer (score 1):

Use `stopImmediatePropagation()`. Also, you can directly use `this.parentNode.innerHTML = ""`. I have replaced the `a` selector by `.blueBox a.remove`, because only the `.remove` anchors inside  .blueBox`` should be affected.

```
$('.blueBox a.remove').click(function (e) {
    e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    this.parentNode.innerHTML = "";
});
```

EDIT: prop **A** gation. Not propOgation.

Comment: still the same behavior as described in my question, div doesn't clear its content and its click event is fired. :(

Comment: Ah I see. You were using `stopPropOgation`, while it should be `propAgation`. Have a look at the updated answer.

Comment: still no luck :(, I have added the full js file in my original question if it helps.

Comment: `div#dialog` is not a child of a `.blueBox`div. That causes the event listener to not be bound to the `a.remove` link.

Answer (score 1):

You can change

```
this.parentNode.innerHTML = ""
```

by

```
$(this).parent().html('')
```

to be more "JQuery"

**EDIT:**

btw: to "Cancel the link behavior" you just have to "return (false);" at the end of the function. I don't know if it could help!